# Notepad++ function list PHP not working if the function name begins with reserverd words

Tags: php, regex, function, plugins, notepad++

The Function List Plugin from notepad++ is working fine, except my function name starts with "for / while / if".

For example i have functions in a form-class. So they start with "form" (e.g. form_information). 
So the function name won't show up in the function list, because the functionname starts with 'for'.

Has someone the same issue, or maybe a solution in the regex for this?

This is the regex and xml of the PHP function list.

```
<parser id="php_function" displayName="PHP" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(//.*?$))">
<classRange
    mainExpr="^[\s]*(class|abstract[\s]+class|final[\s]+class)[\t ]+[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*([\s]*|[\s]*(extends|implements|(extends[\s]+(\\|[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)+[\s]+implements))[\s]+(\,[\s]*|(\\|[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*))+[\s]*)?\{"
    openSymbole = "\{"
    closeSymbole = "\}"
    displayMode="node">
    <className>
        <nameExpr expr="(class|abstract[\s]+class|final[\s]+class)[\s]+[\w]+"/>
        <nameExpr expr="[\s]+[\w]+\Z"/>
        <nameExpr expr="[\w]+\Z"/>
    </className>
    <function
        mainExpr="^[\s]*((static|public|protected|private|final)*(\s+(static|public|protected|private|final))+[\s]+)?(function[\s]+)+([\w]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+))?([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for|switch))[\w_~]+[\s]*\([^\{]*\{">
        <functionName>
            <funcNameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for|switch))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\{]*"/>
            <!-- comment below node if want display method with parmas -->
            <funcNameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for|switch))[\w_]+"/>
        </functionName>
    </function>
</classRange>
<function
    mainExpr="^[\s]*function[\s]+\w+\("

    displayMode="$className->$functionName">
    <functionName>
        <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\("/>
        <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+"/>
    </functionName>
    <className>
        <nameExpr expr="[\w_]+(?=[\s]*::)"/>
    </className>
</function>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Change the `(?!(if|while|for|switch))` to `(?!(if|while|for|switch)\b)`, and `(?!(if|while|for))` yo `(?!(if|while|for)\b)`.. That might help you.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just looked at the **%APPDATA%\Notepad++\functionList.xml**, and it looks like the problem is that `if|while|for|switch` are checked without word boundaries around. You need to add the word boundaries in the proper places. See the modified first `<function>` node:

```
<function
    mainExpr="^[\s]*((static|public|protected|private|final)*(\s+(static|public|protected|private|final))+[\s]+)?(function[\s]+)+([\w]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+))?([\w_]+[\s]*::)?\b(?!(if|while|for|switch)\b)[\w_~]+[\s]*\([^\{]*\{">
    <functionName>
        <funcNameExpr expr="\b(?!(if|while|for|switch)\b)[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\{]*"/>
        <!-- comment below node if want display method with parmas -->
        <funcNameExpr expr="\b(?!(if|while|for|switch)\b)[\w_]+"/>
    </functionName>
</function>
```

The POI is `\b(?!(if|while|for|switch)\b)`  - word boundary before the negative lookahead and right after the alternation group to only match these words as whole words.

[image]

Comment: Yes, mind that you *do* need *both* leading and trailing `\b`s here, since otherwise the lookahead will be executed before each char on  a line - that is unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with you parser is that it tests that the functions names aren't `if`, `while`, `for` or `switch`. But it doesn't check if the name goes on - e.g. `form`. Add a word boundary to the regex and it might help you.

Change the `(?!(if|while|for|switch))` to

```
(?!(if|while|for|switch)\b)
```

and the `(?!(if|while|for))` to

```
(?!(if|while|for)\b)
```

That might help you.